# Can we enable browser location using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, fancybox-2

How can I automatically enable browser location using jQuery? Currently I can detect whether location is enabled or not from the code written below:

```
setInterval(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionFound, positionNotFound);
}, 6000);

function positionFound() {
    return true;
}

function positionNotFound() {
     var template = site_url + 'front/auth/setLocationFancybox';
    if (!$('.fancybox-overlay').html()) {
        $.fancybox.open({
            padding: 0, 
            href: template, 
            type: 'iframe', 
            'closeBtn': false
        });
    }
}
```

In the fancybox there will be two buttons:

1. `Turn on location`: By which browser location will be turned on.
2. `Cancel`: By which current parent window will get closed from the fancybox.

How can I turn on browser location and how can I close parent window from fancybox?

Comment: You can't automatically enable it. It's down to the user's preferences which is out of control of JS.

Comment: There's a reason why the browser asks for permission, you know.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan & Juhana. But can we close the current tab from fancybox. If yes how?? I am using Php- Codeigniter, jQuery, AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to turn on browser location using JavaScript/jQuery. Users need to grant permissions in their preferences. Your best option there is to specifically ask your users to enable it.

To close the parent window from fancybox you can use the following line of code:

```
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Currently I can close the fancybox from this: parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();. Suppose there is a fancy box on my current page. In the fancybox there will be a cancel button. Now on clicking the button I want to close my current tab.

Comment: You can only close tabs that you opened yourself.  You can try: `window.top.close();`.  There are certain things (messing with user settings, closing tabs) that are best left to the *user* to do. For obvious reasons (e.g. malware, bugs), scripts running on web pages have very limited abilities when it comes to doing things "for the user".